# Voit-on jamais "a.m." ou "p.m." dans des pays francophones ?

Tags: indications-de-temps, culture

Je sais bien qu'on ne *dit* jamais

> "On se retrouve à sept heures **a.m.**/**p.m.**"

On dirait, bien sûr:

> "...à sept heures **du soir/du matin**"

ou bien pour préciser l'après-midi ou le soir:

> "...à **quinze heures/dix-neuf heures.**"

Mais est-ce que le **a.m./p.m.** se voit jamais dans des livres ou peut-être des journaux français ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On n'utilise jamais *A.M.* et *P.M.* car c'est du latin (*Ante/Post meridiem*) repris par l'anglais mais cette formulation n'existe simplement pas en français.

À l'oral, on compte les heures indifféremment en base douze ou vingt-quatre, dans le premier cas, on précisera du matin, de l'après-midi ou du soir s'il risque d'y avoir un doute.

À l'écrit, les horaires sont toujours représentés sur vingt-quatre heures donc sans ambiguïté.

Attention, contrairement à l'anglais qui utilise 12h00 pour les deux, on dit en français 0h00 pour minuit et 12h00 pour midi.

Answer (score 5):

Never because we use to write and read in 24h. 
17h15, 5h10...
But we speak in 12 with (in afternoon/in the morning) as you say right. Sometimes in 24h.

A rendez-vous (write or speak) is often in 24h.

Calendar, newspaper, public informations, computers....all are in 24h. (17:15, 5:10...)